# Why is the flag limit different on MSO compared to SO?

Tags: discussion, flags

I was randomly playing around with the flag button<sup>1</sup>, then I noticed something that looks different on MSO compred to SO.
[image: On MSO, I can flag 10 times]
On MSO, I can flag 10 times

----[image: But on SO, I can flag 11 times]
But on SO, I can flag 11 times

Why can I have 1 more flag on SO, but not MSO? Is there a specific reason or is this just a computer malfunction?

---

<sup>1</sup>
Of course, I didn't submit the flags xD.

Comment: Perhaps because what's on topic here is not the same as what's on topic on the main site. Is there some reason you think you'd need hundreds of flags on Meta?

Comment: I don't know.... Maybe one day you see 11 off topic questions??

Comment: That's more than get asked here in a usual day so they'd all have to be off topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of how many flags you get to cast is the number of helpful flags you've previously raised (+1 for every 10 helpful) which is a separate count between main and meta sites.

Since you have (as of time of this post) 13 helpful flags on SO you get a +1 taking you to 11 but none on meta leaving  you 10.

Since reputation is shared between main and meta sites the  +1 flag for each 2k rep applies to both.

Both sites are subject to a maximum of 100 flags per day.